# AJAX Getting Data, Post Back and Get Again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do the following thing with AJAX:

1. Visitor click button/ AJAX show spinning/loading image to visitor.
2. AJAX Visit URL 1 `http://www.mywebsite.com/url1.php` and it'll return a random code, for example `1357`.
3. Then, I want it to visit URL 2 `http://www.mywebsite.com/url2.php?code=1357&action=ask` (`1357` is a variable from url1). URL 2 will verify the request return a final code. I want to show the code to the visitor after removing the spinning/loading image.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I'm fine with steps 1/2, but can't get #3 working. So I'm here looking for the complete code if possible.

Comment: Could you add your current code, please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sD9TrhnV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$.get("http://www.mywebsite.com/url1.php").done(function(data){
    $.get(
       "http://www.mywebsite.com/url2.php",           
       {code: data, action: "ask"}
    ).done(function(next){
       $("#result").html(next);         
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use a variable `ask` for `action` attribute?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine to use variables as data for request. See how i used `data` (which contains response from `url1.php`).

Comment: You need to put `var ask = jQuery('#ask').val();` inside your `click` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/url1.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

        // Show the random code, like 1357
        $(".result").html(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'page2.php?rand_n=' + data, // Change rand_n to what you want
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data2) {

                // Hide the spinning/loading image
                $("#loading_img").hide();

                // Show final code
                $(".result").html(data2);

            }
        });


    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea for you:

Method one:

```
1.ajax request http://www.mywebsite.com/url1.php

2.in url1.php generate a random code like :1357

3.use [curl][1] request http://www.mywebsite.com/url2.php?code=1357&action=ask 

4.echo result from curl2 to frontend
```

above only need one time ajax,the second request use curl quietly..

Method two:

you also could use header to redirect the url:

```
go on with step 2:

step 3:could use header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/url2.php?code=1357&action=ask');

step 4:url2.php should echo the result.
```

this tow method only have one ajax request and won't affect you frontend ,i recommand you use method two,method one is better used in different domain..